# How can I create a vertically scrollable table within a flex container without a fixed height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a table that sits within a flex container that I've designed with a header and footer on either end of a middle "content" area. What I want to accomplish is a layout where the footer is *either* "fixed" at the bottom of the page (if there is content that is not very tall), or is pushed beyond the bottom of the viewport (if the content is very tall).

However, I now have a use case where I'd like to create a table that fills the entire content area, but if it's going to overflow the content area it then allows the user to scroll the contents of the table without pushing the footer beyond the bottom of the viewport.

I know that I could very easily do this if I could just set a `max-height` to a non-calculated value for the table, but since this all kind of rests on the parent container's `min-height` being `100vh` I'm not sure where to go.

Here's some sample code (also [here on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-mniqkk?file=styles.css) with a ton of `<tr>` elements):

```html
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="header">Header</div>
      <div class="content">
        <table class="table">
          [Enough table rows to make the table tall enough...]
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 50px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  height: 50px;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}

.table {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `height` instead of `min-height`, since we want to be more "forceful" about it being the height of the screen. Make the `.content` the scroll container instead of the `<table>` element.

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 50px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  height: 50px;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
      <div class="header">Header</div>
      <div class="content">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Maria Anders</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer—this does solve the problem! I think I had considered making `.content` the scroll container but didn't because I wanted to allow it to be "modular", but I'm realizing that there's nothing preventing me from replacing that content `<div>` with whatever it is that I need. I ran into this in the course of working with a React application where React Router renders a "page" component within that content space—but there's nothing stopping me from just including the content container with the "page" components to be rendered.